# Oracle EXPDP usando el parámetro QUERY con resultados de SELECT

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-12c, oracle-19c

```
dumpfile=TABLE1.dmp
logfile=TABLE1.log
directory=TABLE1
tables=OWNER.TABLE1
QUERY='"WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *  FROM TABLE1 WHERE DSDE_SDET_ID IN 
(SELECT SDET_ID FROM TABLE2 WHERE SDET_SOLI_ID IN (SELECT SOLI_ID FROM TABLE3 WHERE  ku$.SOLI_EMPS_ID=14)))"'
EXCLUDE=CONSTRAINT
EXCLUDE=COMMENT
EXCLUDE=INDEX
EXCLUDE=GRANT
```

Por favor su ayuda necesito realizar un backup, realizando ese query, cuando lo genero exporta todo el esquema y no hace caso a las condiciones.